# to many arguments in while loop bash

Tags: bash, while-loop, arguments

I'm new in bashscripting and I can´t find my failure.

Errorcode:

```
[: too many arguments
```

Script:

```
i=5
while [ "${array[i]}" >= "256" ] -a [ "$i" > "0" ]; do
  array[$i]=0
  i=$(( $i - 1 ))
  array[$i]=$((${array[$i]}+1))
done
```

Comment: `-a` is not inside a `[`/`test`.

Comment: Use `&&` instead of `-a`

Comment: When I change `-a` with `&&` then I have a new Error : `[: 43: unary operator expected`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are trying to do some base 256 carrying. Here is the corrected and simplified script, with an added example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
i=5
array=(254 255 255 255 255 256)
while [ ${array[i]} -ge 256 ] && [ $i -gt 0 ]; do
    array[i]=0
    (( i-- ))
    (( array[i]++ ))
done
echo ${array[@]}
```

Output:

```
255 0 0 0 0 0
```

Honestly I would rather use Bash's arithmetic expansion instead of test, so `[ ${array[i]} -ge 256 ] && [ $i -gt 0 ]` can instead be

```
(( array[i] >= 256 && i > 0 ))
```

Comment: @DrFaust You're welcome. And welcome to SO, you may accept the answer if it solved the problem (check mark on the left).